# jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot find data type 'TEXT' while exporting data to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

I have created a dataframe in scala spark 2.1 on Azue HDInsight. I am trying to write a dataframe to SQL data warehouse using PostgreSQL packages. I tried the below command to write:

```
df1.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://######").option("dbtable", "dbo.Period_ERROR").option("user", "dataiqdw").option("password", "######").save()
```

But I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot find data type 'TEXT'.
  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
```

I am able to read data from SQL data warehouse in a dataframe but i am getting this error only when I am trying to punch data into a table. 
My problem is very similar to [PySpark 2.0 export data to Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850738/pyspark-2-0-export-data-to-azure-sql-server)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying connect to SQL Server instance but it is using Postgres packages in spark 2.1. Also, i can write Integer columns into database, but the moment i am trying with string columns, i am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: It could be that the support of the text type has been removed in your version of SQL Server. Try to create a table with that column type there.

Comment: @Ankan  - I am running into similar issue .were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: Yes change the column type to varchar or String. Remove it from text format will resolve the issue.

Comment: @Ankan, I have the same problem, when I remove string columns , the problem will be solved, so my question is how did you convert string types to varchar?

Comment: @AminMohebi You don't have to convert your data. Just change the particular columns (schema/definition) in your SQL Server table to varchar instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override getJDBCType() method and provide implementation for STRING DataType , As it takes TEXT by default

```
override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = {
    val answer = dt match {
      case TimestampType => Some(JdbcType("DATETIME", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP))
      case StringType => Some(JdbcType("VARCHAR(250)", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
      case _ => None
    }
```